# Why does creating a Python virtual environment change the folder structure?

Tags: python

I'm on Windows and my Python interpreter is Python.exe, and then there is a subfolder named Lib and then another subfolder named "site-packages". Python is set up to search this path relative to itself to find imports. When I create a virtual environment on Windows it puts the Python interpreter .exe inside the /Scripts folder, meaning to find the site-packages it needs to search ../Lib/site-packages. Why does it do this? And how does the interpreter know to search another path? Well, I guess the answer is the path is baked into the python.exe binary to search another path, but why is this the case for virtual environments? It seems it would make more sense to keep the folder structure as normal.

Comment: Because the whole point of the virtualenv is to create an isolated environment? It's not clear what you're asking here. It's a different python interpreter to the one you might have added to PATH

Comment: on Linux it keeps `python` in `/usr/bin/` but `modules` in `/usr/lib/python3.10/
` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages`, and few others - all because other programs keep data in similar way - so it would be problem to use the same structure in `venv`

Comment: @roganjosh Do you have to install EVERY single dependency again in any virtual environment? You can't share with anything else?

Comment: @Zebrafish yes and no. **Yes** in the sense that you will get a fresh install of every library but **no** in the sense that you really only specify the parent libraries and `pip` figures out the dependency tree. So, `pip install pandas`, for example, will pull in `numpy` and probably 10 other libraries. And no, you cannot share them but they may be cached to save an extra dowload - that side I'm less familiar with

Answer (score 1):

It introduces a new directory containing the isolated environment, doesn't really change the folder structure itself

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).